# When flatness of a morphism implies smoothness?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

**EDIT:** Let $f\colon X\to C$ be a flat proper morphism of complex algebraic (or analytic) varieties. Assume the special fiber over a point $p\in C$ is smooth.

**Is it true that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ (in Zariski or analytic topology) such that all fibers of $f$ over $U$ are smooth? Or more precisely, $U$ should be such that the morphism $f\colon f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is smooth.**

In my case one may assume that $C$ is a smooth curve or an infinitesimal neighborhood of a point $p$ inside such a curve, and the fibers of $f$ are one dimensional. The complex analytic situation is particularly important for me, but the algebraic situation is also of interest.

**UPDATE:** As was mentioned by abx in his comment to his answer below, flatness of $f$ and smoothness of the special fiber $f^{-1}(p)$ imply that $f$ is smooth along $f^{-1}(p)$, i.e. $f$ is smooth in a neighborhood of the special fiber. This is the key fact for my question. I was shown a reference to it: Lemma 130.16 here  http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/algebra.pdf

Comment: Your "ADDED" is a completely different question. You should ask it separately.

Comment: @abx: agree. Deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No if you don't assume that $f$ is proper. For a typical example, let $S$ be a  curve with one singular point $s$; take   $X=(S\times C) \smallsetminus \{(s,p)\} $.

On the other hand if you assume $f$ proper, this is (trivially) true: the locus of points $x\in X$ such that $T_x(f)$ is not surjective is a closed subset $F$ of $X$, $f(F)$ is closed and does not contain $p$, just take $U=C \smallsetminus f(F)$.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add the properness. I do not quite understand your notation: what is $T_x(f)$? Also probably I should add that $X$ is not assumed to be smooth.

Comment: @semyonalesker, if $X$ is not smooth, but $C$ is, you don't have a chance that $f$ is smooth (since smoothness is stable under composition). So you might as well assume that $X$ is smooth.

Comment: @semyonalesker : $T_x(f)$ is the tangent map to $f$ at $x$. If you don't assume $X$ smooth, take for $F$ in my answer the set of points $x\in X$ which are either not smooth over $C$, or where $T_x(f)$ is not surjective. This is still a closed subset of $X$ which does not meet $f^{-1}(p)$, hence $U=C\smallsetminus f(F)$ works.

Comment: @abx: How did you use flatness?

Comment: I am using flatness (implicitely) to say that $f$ flat + $f^{-1}(p)$ smooth implies $f$ smooth along $f^{-1}(p)$.

Comment: @abx: thank you. Your solution is too concise for me. It would be great to have a reference to a more detailed exposition.

Comment: I was shown a reference to the last fact you mentioned:  Lemma 130.16 here http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/algebra.pdf